# Prove that if $x$ is the greatest lower bound of $U$, then $x$ is the least upper bound of $B$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, order-theory

Not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231617/prove-if-x-is-greatest-lower-bound-of-u-then-x-is-the-least-upper-bound-of) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402643/prove-that-if-x-is-the-greatest-lower-bound-of-u-then-x-is-the-least-uppe).

This is exercise $4.4.21.c$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $B\subseteq A$. Let $U$ be the set of all upper bounds for $B$.

$(c)$ Prove that if $x$ is the greatest lower bound of $U$, then $x$ is the least upper bound of $B$.

Here is my proof:

Suppose $x$ is the $g.l.b.$ of $U$. We define $L=\{y|\forall z\in U(yRz)\}$ to be the set of all the lower bounds of $U$ and so we have $\forall l\in L(lRx)$. Let $b$ be an arbitrary element of $B$. Since $b$ is a lower bound for $U$, $b\in L$. From $\forall l\in L(lRx)$ and $b\in L$, $bRx$. Since $b$ is arbitrary, $x\in U$. Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of $U$ and so $\forall b\in B(bRu)$. Since $x\in L$, $\forall z\in U(xRz)$. Since $u\in U$, $xRu$. Since $u$ is arbitrary, $x$ is the smallest element of $U$. Since $x\in U$ and $\forall u\in U(xRu)$, $x$ is the $l.u.b.$ of $B$. Therefore if $x$ is the $g.l.b.$ of $U$ then $x$ is the $l.u.b.$ of $B$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Everything seems to be OK, but you should take more care about the use of quantifiers and related notation in text mode (inline). This can be read in a way which is not what you want. With this I mean that, translating the symbols into English (or whatever language you prefer), this sometimes becomes ungrammatical or even grammatical, but with a different meaning.

Comment: @amrsa Could you please explain more?

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: It’s fine, and I disagree with the earlier comment, though in writing it up I would replace the quantifiers with English expressions (e.g., ‘and so we have $\ell\,R\,x$ for each $\ell\in L$’).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much.

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh I didn't mean necessarily the above proof, but I think this style will more often lead to such errors. Now, hit is true that serious grammatical errors happen in other situations. So perhaps it is just my disliking of this style that makes have this prejudice. So never mind. But I think it is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Today I solved this problem again and I noticed that

"Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of $U$ and so $\forall b\in B(bRu)$. Since $x\in L$, $\forall z\in U(xRz)$. Since $u\in U$, $xRu$. Since $u$ is arbitrary, $x$ is the smallest element of $U$."

is a little redundant and could be written as

"Since $x\in L$, from the definition of $L$ we obtain $\forall z\in U(xRz)$ which means that $x$ is the smallest element of $U$."

which is correct and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more appropriate to begin by assuming that there is some $u_\in U$, since $x$ is the l.u.b. of $B$ means that $x$ is the smallest element of $U$. This is the proof I wrote:

Suppose that $x$ is g.l.b. of $U$. Suppose $u_2\in U$, and so we have to prove that $xR_2$ and $x\in U$. Suppose $b\in B$, so our new goals are $xRu_2$, $bRx$, and $x\in A$. Let $L_U$ be the set of l.b. of $U$. Since x is g.l.b. of $U$, then it is the largest element of $L_U$. Thus, $\forall m_1\in U (xRm_1)$ and $x\in A$. Given that $\forall m_1\in U (xRm_1)$ and $u_2\in U$, then $xRu_2$. Also, since $u_2\in U$, it follows that $\forall b\in B (bRu_2)$ and $u_2\in A$. Since $b\in B$ and $\forall b\in B (bRu_2)$, then $bRu_2$. Given that $x,u_2\in A$, then $u_2Rx$. Since $R$ is a partial order, then it is transitive on $A$. Given that $bRu_2$ and $u_2Rx$, then $bRx$. Since $u_2$ was an arbitrary element of $U$, then $x\in U$. Since $u_2$ was an arbitrary element of $U$, then $x$ is a l.u.b. of $B$.